# AJAX is not looping

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have this html and ajax file, but it is not updating every second like I want it to. I want it to every second call getTime(). It only does it once, then nothing.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
<head>
    <title>Auction</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTime() {
            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","functions.php?action=getCurrentTime&id=13",true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            setTimeout(getTime, 1000);
        }

        window.setInterval(getTime, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php beginGetAllInfo(); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code, the first thing that happens inside `getTime()` is it checks if a variable named `str` is empty, if so, it returns from the function. `str` isn't defined (in your sample code), so it should return. Try removing that `if`-statement, or initialize `str` to something that won't cause the statement to fail.

Additionally, you have two statements that will (eventually) cause your code to execute twice per second:
`setTimeout(getTime, 1000);`
and
`window.setInterval(getTime, 1000);`

The first, `setTimeout()` will execute the code one-time, after 1-second has elapsed. However, this is executed everytime the `getTime()` method executes - so in theory it should run every second.
The second, `setInterval()` will execute the code on an interval of 1-second. So, your code will always execute every 1 second.

I'd recommend either removing the `setTimeout()` line inside of `getTime()`, or changing the `setInterval()` to a `setTimeout()` (to get the ball rolling, so to speak).